# Add 2 weeks to a date SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have to insert a date in a DB and I want to set the end date 2 weeks after that date.

How can I make it?

in my select, I guess there is needed something like:

```
insert into table values (current_Date, current_Date+2weeks) where....
```

But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: MySQL, I already added. I forgot

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow things happen fast. It is always a good idea to stick around at least for the first 5 minutes after asking to answer to comments.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

for mysql

```
INSERT INTO tbl(fromdate,todate) values (now(), DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL 2 WEEK))
```

for sql server

```
 INSERT INTO tbl(fromdate,todate) values( current_timestamp, DATEADD(week,2,current_timestamp))
```